# Alternative title to header, but without number

Tags: header-footer

I am new with tex and hope that my question is clear and easy to answer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{ \markboth{#1}{} }
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{ \markright{#1}{} }

\begin{document}

    \section[O\lowercase{rganization of ma\uppercase{RNA}}]{maRNA%
    \sectionmark{O\lowercase{rganization of ma\uppercase{RNA}}}}

\end{document}
```

I need to add alternative section title in the header (provided in the `[]`). However, besides alternative title section number goes their too.

Question:  How can I add alternative title to the header, without adding section number?

--

Please understand that I am only starting with latex and my code might be illogical as it is compilation of things that work for me.

Comment: What's the reason for `\lowercase` and `\uppercase`? You can easily change the header appearance with `fancyhdr` features (look for `\nouppercase`). It's not clear what `\chaptermark` should do in `article`.

Comment: Terms that I am using(eg., maRNA) have both lower an uppercase. I didn't know how to deal with it as header makes them all uppercase if I don't specify.

Comment: The main question is: why don't you want the number? If you have it for some sections, there should be for all.

Comment: Because for most of my document subsection titles goes into the header. Now there is page with new section starting in it and there is no subsection in that page, hence section title goes into the header. And I need to change its structure as it is not the same what was with subsections.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My try:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[R]{\nouppercase{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[C]{\thepage}

\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}
\renewcommand{\subsectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}


\begin{document}

\title{A title}
\author{A. Uthor}

\maketitle

\section{maRNA}

\subsection{Organization of maRNA}

\lipsum[1-12]

\subsection{Something else on maRNA}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Can you please explain `\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{}`?

Comment: @Poe Usually `\sectionmark` issues `\markboth{<...>}{}` so setting the `\leftmark`. By redefining it to do nothing, only the `\rightmark` will be set by `\subsection`. You can still have an empty header in the second page if no subsection starts in the first or second page, which is unlikely.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}

\section*{Organization of maRNA}
\markright{Organization of maRNA}

\end{document}
```